# How can I make the title of my select element be equal to the title of the selected option?

Tags: jquery

I have a select that looks like this:

```
<select id="select-site" title="????">
   <optgroup label="City">
      <option title="ee" value="1">123</option>
      <option title="cc" value="2">456</option>
      <option title="dd " value="3">789</option>
      <option title="xx" selected="selected" value="4">aa</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

How can I make it so that after the document has loaded the title of the select which is ???? is changed to the title of the selected option. Also how can I make it so that when I change the selected option the title of the `<select>` is updated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for complete solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-site').change(function() {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).find('option:selected').attr('title'));
    });
    $('#select-site').trigger('change');
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#select-site').change(function() {
var selectedVal = $('#select-site option:selected').attr('title');
$('#select-site').attr("title",selectedVal) ;
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Still need to be wrapped into `$(document).ready();` and must be called one time manually, so that the initial title is set.

Comment: no you don't have to it's automatically take the selected item i tried it and it definitely work

Comment: Does not work in Safari, FireFox and Chrome. The `change` is never triggered as there did no change happen yet.

Answer (score 1):

This will set the `title` attribute of `#select-site` as the `title` of the selected `option`

```
$('#select-site').change(function() {
  $(this).prop('title', $('option:selected', this).prop('title'));
});
```

To set the initial value of the `title` attribute you need to `trigger` the change event:-

`$('#select-site').trigger('change');`

or

`$('#select-site').change();`

All of this would need to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()` as pointed out in the comments below.

Comment: Still need to be wrapped into `$(document).ready();` and must be called one time manually, so that the initial title is set.

Comment: Good answer. You'r still missing one point. The user wants the `title`-attribute from the òption` to be used. So either `.val()` nor `.text()` will work. :)

Comment: Yeah I hadn't noticed that until just now :( I've updated my answer

Comment: Best answer now as it also uses `this`, so no extra re-selection is necessary during the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#select-site').change(function(){
     value = $(this + ' option:selected').val();
     $(this).attr('title',value);
});
```

It will work.

Comment: This solutions sets the value to the title. The OP wants the title attribute to be used. Still need to be wrapped into `$(document).ready();` and must be called one time manually, so that the initial title is set.